# Pointer to overloaded bound-member function as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, generics, function-pointers

I am working on a small signal dispatcher implementation and I have hit a problem I cannot seem to solve. I tried to find info on the internet but came up short on this specific problem.

I am trying to give a function template a function pointer to an overloaded bound member function, via a template parameter. The function is called "connect". I am using auto for the template parameter which holds the function pointer but the compiler says "no matching overloaded function found" when I try to call the function.

I have implemented a second connect function where I specify the function pointer type in the template parameter (instead of using auto) and with this function it works.

Maybe someone can explain to me, why the first connect function doesn't work for the overloaded member function. I am probably missing something about template parameter deduction but I cannot find out what it is.

Here is the code (C++ 17 and above):

```
struct EventHandler
{
  EventHandler() = default;

  void handleEventOverloaded(int x)
  {
    z = x;
  }

  void handleEventOverloaded(float x)
  {
    z = static_cast<int>(x);
  }

  void handleEvent(float x)
  {
    z = static_cast<int>(x);
  }

  int z = 0;
};

class Dispatcher
{
public:
  template <typename EventType, auto Function, typename InstanceType>
  auto connect(InstanceType& instance)
  {
    auto f = Function;
    int x = 0;
  }

  template <typename EventType, void(EventHandler::* Function)(float), typename InstanceType>
  auto connect2(InstanceType& instance)
  {
    auto f = Function;
    int x = 0;
  }
};


int main()
{
  Dispatcher dispatcher{};
  EventHandler evHandler{};


  dispatcher.connect<float, &EventHandler::handleEventOverloaded>(evHandler);  //Error: no matching overloaded function found   
  dispatcher.connect<float, &EventHandler::handleEvent>(evHandler);  //OK: bound non-overloaded member function
  dispatcher.connect2<float, &EventHandler::handleEventOverloaded>(evHandler); //OK: bound overloaded member function

  //Test if the function pointer works
  void(EventHandler:: * evHandlerFunc)(float) = &EventHandler::handleEventOverloaded;
  ((&evHandler)->*evHandlerFunc)(5.5f);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are searching for:

> For pointers to members, the argument has to be a pointer to member expressed as &Class::Member or a constant expression that evaluates to null pointer or std::nullptr_t (since C++11) value.

Here is the full [Template parameters and template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) page from cppreference.com if you want to read it yourself.